# Httrack and cookies, my files appear like not logged

Tags: google-chrome, clone, httrack

I want download all videos and images of a course in a webpage..

I am using **httrack** command line.. and I've downloaded my cookies with a extension chrome...

I've set the `cookies.txt` in the proyect folder...

- In my cookie I'm logged in the webpage as premium member

But when I scanned with my httrack it did not access the premium section and the **index.html** look as **normal user**, *not logged*

This is the command used by me

```
httrack https://www.MYWEB.com/courses/take/Courses/ -O /root/websites/proyectXDD -p3 -B -d -b0
```

What should I do?... I'm sure that the cookies are okay